# reading credentials from jenkins credential manager and integrating with python script

Tags: python, batch-file, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins, credential-manager

I have a python script which is making a couple of api calls and returning the response to me via email. I want to run this script through a jenkins pipeline job.
I have a token, which I have stored in the jenkins credential manager as a secret text.
The problem is that I am unsure as how to fetch this token in my python script. I have tried looking at a number of solutions, but all of those are leaving me confused.
This is what my jenkins pipeline looks like:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'node1'
        }
    }
    environment {
        deva_stross_token=credentials('devadrita-stross') //i have saved the credential with id 'devadrita-stross', and this I understand, is fetching it for my pipeline
    }
    stages {
        stage('running python script') {
            steps {
                script {
                    bat """
                    python -u C://Users//Administrator//Desktop//stross//stross-script.py
                    """
                }
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

But what changes should I make to fetch it to my script?
Here is the python script.

```
import requests
import urllib3
import json
import time
import os

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

def initiateScan():
    url = ""

    payload={}
    files=[
    ('source',('amail.zip',open('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/stross/amail.zip','rb'),'application/zip')),
    ('metadata',('metadata.json',open('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/stross/metadata.json','rb'),'application/json'))
    ]
    headers = {
    'Authorization': ' Bearer **<token required here>**'
    }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files, verify=False)

    resp=response.json()
    print(resp)
    
    jobId=resp["job_id"]
    return(jobId)
    
def main():
   jobIdFromInitiate=initiateScan()

main()
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

EDIT-
I understand that there are a few ways to do this, one with credentials() and one with environment variables. The problem is that I am mixing the two up and am not able to implement either method through code. So please help with code.

EDIT 1-
Dividing @rok's answer into steps to follow-
"(1)Add withCredentials block to your Jenkinsfile for reading the credentials and (2)binding them to environment variables. Then, (3)pass the values of the environment variables to your python script as arguments."

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'node1'
        }
    }
    environment {
        deva_stross_token=credentials('devadrita-stross')
    }
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'devadrita-stross', variable: 'deva-stross-token')]) {
    // some block
    }
    stages {
        stage('saving stross token and printing') {
            steps {
                script {
                    bat """
                    python -u C://Users//Administrator//Desktop//stross//stross-script.py
                    """
                }
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

(1) added withCredentials block for reading credentials
(2) what is meant by binding the credentials with environment variables? Did the withCredentials block bind the token to environment variable 'deva-stross-token'? Is my environment block useful or needed here?
(3) how to pass values of the environment variables to my python script?

I feel like I should add that I am relatively new to coding, so please bear with me if my questions seem very basic.

Comment: If you define an environment variable in the global `environment` directive, then it will be an in-process environment variable for any processes spawned by step methods including `bat`. This means you can read an environment variable named `deva_stross_token` from within the Python script. Does that work for you?

Comment: Hi @MattSchuchard. I have declared an environment variable named `deva_stross_token` in the pipeline, if that is what you mean. What would be the syntax to read it from within my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:
Jenkinsfile:

```
stages {
        stage('run stross script') {
            steps{
                withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'devadrita-stross', variable: 'my_stross_token')]) {
                echo "My stross token is '${my_stross_token}'!"
                bat "python C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\stross\\stross-script.py "
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This binds my credential to the specified environment variable.
I then import the variable to my python script, and use it like any other variable, i.e.- pass it to functions, etc.
Here is a code snippet:

```
def main():
    token = os.environ['my_stross_token']
    print(token)
    jobIdFromInitiate=initiateScan(token)
    getStatus(jobIdFromInitiate, token)
```

Comment: an alternative to reading the credentials from `os.environ` would be defining script arguments in python code and passing the credentials to python script as arguments in Jenkinsfile, e.g. `python3 script.py --creds ${my_stross_token}`

Answer (score 1):

Use [Credentials Binding](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials-binding/) plugin. Add `withCredentials` block to your Jenkinsfile for reading the credentials and binding them to environment variables. Then, pass the values of the environment variables to your python script as arguments.

Jenkins  [docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/) list supported credentials types and various bindings.

Comment: Hi. I have gone through all these docs but am unable to translate into code. Could you help with code please? FYI- I need to pass the credential to my python script.

Comment: please show us the effort (your code) and what errors/difficulties you faced. It will be easier to understand how to help. Regarding passing the credential to your python script, I wrote exactly how to do that.